# How can I import users from WordPress to Craft CMS?

Tags: users, craft-pro, import

I want to import users from WordPress to Craft CMS. How can I do that?

Comment: Be sure to check out the Legacy Login plugin too. Makes for a nice workflow for your migrated users: https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/Legacy-Login

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to export users from WordPress, but importing them in Craft can be done with a plugin like [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe). There are other plugins out there too depending on the export file you can get out of WordPress.

If you don't know how to export users from WordPress, you'd need to ask that on the WordPress SE if that exists :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had pretty good luck importing things into Craft using the [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) plugin.  If you can export your Wordpress users into a .csv file you should be able to use that to import them into Craft.  It looks like there are several ways to [export users from Wordpress to a CSV file](https://www.google.com/search?q=export%20wordpress%20users%20to%20a%20.csv%20file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).